# Rails 3 add new routes to resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, routes

I have the following problem:

I created one entity "Film" with the command "scaffold" and  automatically added in my routes file "resources: films", and then I try to added an autocomplete via ajax, but always the calling ajax calls the "show" action instead of call the route that I added "autocomplete_term"

My routes files (routes.rb)

```
resources :films
```

I tried the following possibilities (routes.rb)

```
match 'films/autocomplete_term' => "films#index", :via=>:get
match "films/autocomplete_term/:term" => "films#autocomplete_term",    :controller=>"films", :action=>"autocomplete_term", :as => :films_autocomplete, :via => :get
resources :films do
  collection do
    get 'autocomplete_term'
  end
end
```

The route

** localhost.com:3000/films/autocomplete_term?term=a**

The ERROR

Couldn't find Film with id=autocomplete_term

app/controllers/films_controller.rb:28:in `show'

When I run the command rake routes

```
  GET    /films/autocomplete_term/:term(.:format) films#autocomplete_term
  films_autocomplete 
  GET    /films/autocomplete_term/:term(.:format) films#autocomplete_term
```

autocomplete_term_films 
      GET    /films/autocomplete_term(.:format)       films#autocomplete_term

Sorry for my English

And thanks in advance

Comment: Try `localhost.com:3000/films/autocomplete_term/a`

Comment: Thanks Anezio you're right!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url to access this route

```
GET    /films/autocomplete_term/:term
```

should be

```
localhost.com:3000/films/autocomplete_term/a
```

if you do `localhost.com:3000/films/autocomplete_term?term=a` it will think it is the show action, it will ignore the ?term=a

```
GET    /films/:id
```

Comment: Thank Anezio but how change the "source" in jQueryUI because my route is being http://localhost:3000/films/autocomplete_term/undefined?term=aa

Comment: The standard url if I'm not wrong should be `localhost:3000/films/autocomplete_term?term=aa`. So you should create a route for that, could be `match 'films/autocomplete_term' => "films#autocomplete_term"` I believe

Comment: Thanks again!! ... I tried but did not work. Same error "Couldn't find Film with id=autocomplete_term"

Comment: The route `match 'films/autocomplete_term' => "films#autocomplete_term"` should be above the `resources :films` in your routes.rb

Comment: Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action’s route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.    source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anezio, solved the problem, basicament had two things wrong:

1 - The route

```
match "films / autocomplete_term /: term"
```

2: The order in my routes.rb file (Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified)

```
resources: films
match 'films / autocomplete_term /: term' => "films # autocomplete_term"
```

The Final Solution: (routes.rb)

```
match 'films / autocomplete_term' => "films # autocomplete_term"
resources: films
```